# ACCESS 2000 REPORT

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2000

I have a query which pulls data based on a from and to date. It pulls eight fields which is all fine.

The problem i am having is the report that i create from this,  i need to group by the site name which is all fine i get the site name and the rows under the site name 
( site name can have multiple rows under it. )

The problem i am having is i need to keep each site name and rows on one page so i can design the report for one record per page.

I have tried the page break but it does not seem to work. 
Basically the report will have the site name and under the site name i have a few rows of data, i just want all of this on one page.

Answer (score 1):

In the Properties for the [site name] Group Header you'll want to set the `Force New Page` property to `Before Section`, like this:

[image: header.png]

Comment: Gord thank you very much the one thing i didn't try lol...your a star thanks alot!!